Geocentrism and annual tide variation
I have read that in the before common era, Seleucus of Seleucia have studied tides and probably used annual variation as an evidence of heliocentric. However, tides are known to be affected by position of both sun and moon in relation to earth that's why it is affected by seasons too but ptolemy's model could explain moon phases, seasons and eclipses. So can it explain annual, monthly and diurnal variation in tides (with excluding the idea that they didn't know about about gravity) ?
Note: I tried roughly remodeling this but it seemed to be too hard and complex for a novice in astronomy like me
